# Can someone help me identify this spider?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Can someone help me identify this spider? Saw it in Malawi; aprox. 5 to 6 cm. Seems like a Solifugae but I cannot go any further... I thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: That is a sun spider. It is in the order Solifugae, family Solpugidae. I don't know the species. Looks like genus Zeria.

Comment: Just to make it clear - although Solifugids are arachnids, they are not spiders.  Those big heavy 'pincers' in front of the face are the useful ID factor.  They are not venomous (as far as I know), but the pincers can give you quite a nip, like a crab or lobster.

Answer (score 2):

According to [museum.wa.gov.au](http://museum.wa.gov.au/catalogues-beta/distribution-browser/solifugae/mw), there are four solifugid species in Malawi. *Ceroma johnstonii*, *Ceroma zomba*, *Zeria niassa* and *Zeria paludicola*.

*[Ceroma johnstonii](https://books.google.com/books?id=18pMAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA254&lpg=PA254&dq=ceroma%20johnstonii&source=bl&ots=V01fnqRnQd&sig=ACfU3U2JUsdQzpYT-Lfh2ax-ejBobNWO3Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv3sTg8cvpAhUFCM0KHZgJCUoQ6AEwA3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=ceroma%20johnstonii&f=false)* has a grayish-brown tint, not the dark brown, almost black coloration (and red) of your solifugid. *Ceroma zomba* is only 8 mm in length, much too small even if your estimate of 50-60 mm was referring to the legspan.

*[Zeria niassa](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeria_niassa)* is only 24-28 mm in body length, significantly smaller than what you saw unless you meant legspan. *Zeria paludicola* is also smaller than your 50-60 mm estimate, so it must have been the legspan, not the length. The only photo I could find of any *Zeria* species is from [eol.org](https://eol.org/media/8890088) and is of an unspecified species. In the photo, it has a dark brown coloration and a very faint tinge of red on the side of the abdomen.

[image]

So your image is either of *Zeria niassa* or *Zeria paludicola*.